# PHP - Why is my preg_match not working?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to make sure that when the user registers they use a specific series of characters. In my case i want them to enter something like "d1111111" so I want it to be 8 characters in total and to start with the letter d lowercase or uppercase, to allow the other 7 characters to be a number between 0 and 9. All help appreciated, thanks.

here's my code so far

```
$regex = '/[d][0-9]{8}/';

if(preg_match($regex, $username)){
    echo "Valid";
} else {
    echo "not a valid username";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use for example

```
$regex = '/^[dD][0-9]{7}$/';
```

or

```
$regex = '/^d\d{7}$/i';
```

A [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[…]` matches a *single* character, `[dD]` therefore matches the letter `d` *or* `D`.

Alternatively, you can use the `i` option (also referred to as *modifier*) at the end of the expression, to let your regular expression match case-insensitively. It is also possible to [change the mode inside the expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), I personally have never used that, though.

`\d` matches any digit and is the same as `[0-9]`. `{7}` denotes how many digits to match.

You need `^` and `$` to ensure that the regular expression matches the whole username.

For PHP in particular, see [PHP's PCRE docs](http://php.net/manual/de/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

Comment: `d` is supposed to be uppercase or lowercase. Now just lowercase

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong here. First, there's no need of a character class to capture `d`. Just a literal `d` along with *start-of-the-string* anchor `^`.

Now we want the remaining **`7`** letters to be digits. So it would be following with the *end-of-the-string* anchor `$`

```
$regex = '/^d\d{7}$/'
```